# IsChanged Flow Entry Criteria when record is created

Tags: visual-workflow, entry-criteria

I'm relatively new to my current company and am working through an audit of all of our flows. Upon testing, I am realizing that for all flows, when a Flow is set to run when `A record is created or updated`, and if you use `FieldA IsChanged=True` as part of your Entry Criteria for the flow, it will never run on creation, even though FieldA is going from Null to ValueA. The only workaround I've found is using a Formula as the entry criteria where `RecordPrior.FieldA <> Record.FieldA` or `RecordPrior.FieldA == Null && Record.FieldA <> Null`

Am I missing something here? This appears to be a pretty serious bug or oversight on Salesforce's end, but I want to make sure this isn't something I might be overlooking on my end before I either raise the flag with Salesforce and/or spend several days rewriting/retesting our flows.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

From the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_ischanged_operator.htm&type=5&release=232):

> The `Is Changed` operator is available for flows that are triggered
> when a record is updated. The `Is Changed` operator isn’t available
> for flows that are triggered when a record is created or deleted.

When the record is created, the value doesn't change because no previous value exists. Thus `Is Changed` won't evaluate.

The formula-based approach you've outlined is the current best practice for working around this in a 'create or update' trigger.

`Is Changed` implementation is a classic trade-off where no solution is perfect. Having separate flows for create vs update is already possible yet many prefer having these two triggers in one flow. When you select `created or updated`, should Flow Builder put up a warning that `Is Changed` doesn't apply to update? Possible but doing so would set a precedent and corresponding expectation for all other scenarios that may deserve a warning. Plus, it's already a busy screen.

Nevertheless, we agree with you that this UX can be improved. Feel free to create an idea on [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search) and get 10,000 or so other users to upvote it, then something might happen. You have our vote.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I searched for about 30 minutes and couldn't find anything. That link mixed with your input is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with testing this in many flows. I was able to utilize a ISNEW() in my entry criteria. Then I used a split decision that if ISNEW() = True, then go down the new path for (Create/Update Flow). However, if ISNEW() = False, then go down the update path.

I agree, this could be improved however I figured i'd share as this made my life a bit easier working through the flows and wondering why they were not firing in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we can use $Record_Prior = null to check is is a new record or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this conversation! I used your suggestion, Jake, and tweaked the formula because I could not get it to work. Not sure if ISNEW() function was available when this was originally posted, but I've tested and this works when I select `a record is created or updated` and criteria `formula evaluates to true`:

`OR({!$Record__Prior.field}<>{!$Record.field},ISNEW())`