# Salesforce flow with Scheduled Paths seems not to honour Entry Conditions

Tags: visual-workflow, record, scheduled

I'm trying to get a flow to run a scheduled path (Only on scheduled path). Expectation is to get a Time based workflow entry (Under Setup->Time based Workflows) so that scheduled path would be executed accordingly.

I have selected **Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements option in entry criteria**.

But it seems not creating the Time based workflow entry to run the  scheduled path unless the field value is changed **to** meet the criteria (e.g. It runs and create time based workflow entry only when Zendesk_Ticket_Created__c is updated with true).

It appears to honour **2nd When to run option than 1st (i.e. Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements)**.

If I used "Run Immediately" path it runs fine **with 1st When to Run** option.

Start Configuration:
[image: Start configuration]

Sample flow POC:
[image]

Scheduled Path config:
[image]

Any help to figure out my understanding is not right? Is this an intended Salesforce behaviour? Any documentation to support that Scheduled paths treat both When to run conditions similarly?

As a workaround I tried to use LastmodifiedDate along with other conditions with AND, but it did not trigger the scheduled path for some reason.

***Note***

Few more observations: Interestingly debug run shows the full successful path correctly, but when you update record manually realistically it did not create the Time based workflow entry, also debug log didn't include flow start which sounded not right to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question/expectation is unclear. Are you expecting it to run the non-scheduled path when the record is created and `Zendesk_Ticjet_Created__c` is `false` ?

Comment: What are you updating? Not 5he current record right? Cause that will throw you in a loop. Can you show the delay setting?

Comment: Hi @identigral, userRR I have updated the question with more details. This is a POC flow to show the problem, Ideally it should create a Timebased flow entry when the record is updated (any field) and at that time the entry condition is fulfilled. But as I observed it didn't create time based flow entry. Thanks!

Comment: The entry criteria are not going to be met when the record is created because the value isn't updated at create time. Semantics and language but it does matter in this case. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382101/ischanged-flow-entry-criteria-when-record-is-created for a related issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I add scheduled paths to a record-triggered flow, the behavior for the two "When to Run the Flow for Updated Records" ("Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements" and "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements") are reversed. Did you ever find a solution to this issue?