# Should a Before-Save record-triggered Flow fire when a record is created from a Composite REST API call?

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, record

We are creating records in our organization by making [Composite Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite_post.htm) through the REST API. For the most part, things are working as intended.

However, none of our Before-Save (Fast Field Update) record-triggered Flows are being run on the newly created records. Those Flows are being run as expected when we create a record through the user interface, but not through our REST calls.

The [Salesforce Platform - Order of Execution Overview](https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png) seems to suggest that they should be running. Attempts to find any authoritative answer within the Salesforce documentation have not been successful.

If we make a `POST` REST API call using a `CompositeRequest` to create records, should we expect the Before-Save Flows to run for each created record? If so, what might be causing them not to run? If not, is there any way to make them run?

**Edit #1: This is the Flow's `Start`**

When a `Rental Agreement` is created or update, and one of two fields has changed, then we want this Flow to be run. (The flow then copies some values from the related `Freight_Rate__c` into fields on the `Rental_Agreement__c` itself.

When `Rental_Agreements__c` is created from the Salesforce UI, it works as expected. When created from a Composite REST API call, the `Rental_Agreement__c` is created, but this Flow is not run. (Or if it is run, we're not seeing the output as we do when run from the UI.)

[image]

Comment: Can you add your condition of workflow trigger or conditions on which specific actions might be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isChanged operator doesn't work on the Insert condition. You can change your your logic to a formula like `RecordPrior.FieldA <> Record.FieldA or RecordPrior.FieldA == Null && Record.FieldA <> Null`. This workaround will solve this issue. [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382101/ischanged-flow-entry-criteria-when-record-is-created#:~:text=The%20Is%20Changed%20operator%20is%20available%20for%20flows,previous%20value%20exists.%20Thus%20Is%20Changed%20won%27t%20evaluate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382101/ischanged-flow-entry-criteria-when-record-is-created#:%7E:text=The%20Is%20Changed%20operator%20is%20available%20for%20flows,previous%20value%20exists.%20Thus%20Is%20Changed%20won%27t%20evaluate).

Comment: Turns out the previous experience was always by updating a record, not creating one. This answer will probably fix another bug in a Flow that was implemented the same way. Thank you.